# How do I only show the 3 with highest scores?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make it so only the 3 with the highest scores show up. How would I make it only echo 3 times with the highest scores?

Right now it goes through and echos every input. It should show up as a top 3 list with best scores, their names, and their picture.

I have tried with the max($ar) but I cant get it to show both image, score and name together.

```
$n1 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name1');
$n2 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name2');
$n3 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name3');
$n4 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name4');
$n5 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name5');
$n6 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name6');
$n7 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name7');
$n8 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name8');
$n9 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name9');
$n10 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name10');
$n11 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name11');
$n12 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name12');
$n13 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name13');
$n14 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name14');
$n15 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name15');
$n16 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name16');
$n17 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name17');
$n18 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name18');
$n19 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name19');
$n20 = get_option('scoreboard_option_name20');
$s1 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score1');
$s2 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score2');
$s3 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score3');
$s4 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score4');
$s5 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score5');
$s6 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score6');
$s7 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score7');
$s8 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score8');
$s9 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score9');
$s10 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score10');
$s11 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score11');
$s12 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score12');
$s13 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score13');
$s14 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score14');
$s15 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score15');
$s16 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score16');
$s17 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score17');
$s18 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score18');
$s19 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score19');
$s20 = get_option('scoreboard_option_score20');
$p1 = get_option('scoreboard_image1');
$p2 = get_option('scoreboard_image2');
$p3 = get_option('scoreboard_image3');
$p4 = get_option('scoreboard_image4');
$p5 = get_option('scoreboard_image5');
$p6 = get_option('scoreboard_image6');
$p7 = get_option('scoreboard_image7');
$p8 = get_option('scoreboard_image8');
$p9 = get_option('scoreboard_image9');
$p10 = get_option('scoreboard_image10');
$p11 = get_option('scoreboard_image11');
$p12 = get_option('scoreboard_image12');
$p13 = get_option('scoreboard_image13');
$p14 = get_option('scoreboard_image14');
$p15 = get_option('scoreboard_image15');
$p16 = get_option('scoreboard_image16');
$p17 = get_option('scoreboard_image17');
$p18 = get_option('scoreboard_image18');
$p19 = get_option('scoreboard_image19');
$p20 = get_option('scoreboard_image20');
$cp1 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage1');
$cp2 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage2');
$cp3 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage3');
$cp4 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage4');
$cp5 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage5');
$cp6 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage6');
$cp7 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage7');
$cp8 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage8');
$cp9 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage9');
$cp10 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage10');
$cp11 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage11');
$cp12 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage12');
$cp13 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage13');
$cp14 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage14');
$cp15 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage15');
$cp16 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage16');
$cp17 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage17');
$cp18 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage18');
$cp19 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage19');
$cp20 = get_option('scoreboard_carimage20');
    
    
$namelist = array($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4, $n5, $n6, $n7, $n8, $n9, $n10, $n11, $n12, $n13, $n14, $n15, $n16, $n17, $n18, $n19, $n20, );
$scorelist = array($s1, $s2, $s3, $s4,$s5, $s6, $s7, $s8, $s9, $s10,$s11,$s12,$s13,$s14,$s15,$s16,$s17,$s18,$s19,$s20 );
$picturelist = array($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8, $p9, $p10, $p11, $p12, $p13, $p14, $p15, $p16, $p17, $p18, $p19, $p20 );
$carlist = array($cp1, $cp2, $cp3, $cp4, $cp5, $cp6, $cp7, $cp8, $cp9, $cp10, $cp11, $cp12, $cp13, $cp14, $cp15, $cp16, $cp17, $cp18, $cp19, $cp20 );

$carlist = array($cp1, $cp2, $cp3, $cp4, $cp5, $cp6, $cp7, $cp8, $cp9, $cp10, $cp11, $cp12, $cp13, $cp14, $cp15, $cp16, $cp17, $cp18, $cp19, $cp20 );


?>

    <div class="row">
    <?php
    $i = -1;
    foreach ($namelist as $name) {
    $i++;   

        
    echo '

        <div class="column" style="float: left; width: 33.33%; padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 35px; border-bottom: 2px solid red; height: 493px;">
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_0  et_pb_text_align_center">
                <div class="et_pb_code_inner">'.$imgPlaceholder.'</div>
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_1  et_pb_text_align_center">
                <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
                    <h2 style="font-size: calc(0.7em + 1vw)">', $namePlaceholder, '</h2>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_2  et_pb_text_align_center">
                <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
                    <h4> <b>
                            ', $scorelist[$i], ' point
                        </b>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
            <div class="et_pb_code_inner" style="
    text-align: center;
">

<a href="', $carlist[$i] ,'" class="et_pb_lightbox_image"><img src="', $carlist[$i] ,'" alt="" class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-30280" width="200"></a>

</div>
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->

';
        
    

}
?>
        </div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: If at all possible, this should probably start by using a better suited data structure to begin with.

Comment: Is this database related?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the way your data is structured is not ideal. So I've changed that for you so we can manipulate things properly. Bear in mind that I didn't test this so you may have to tweak some things yourself but this is more or less what you need to do.

```
<?php
// Structure data into an associative array in order to easily access related data
$racers = array();
for ($n=1; $n<21; $n++) {
    array_push($racers, array(
        get_option("scoreboard_option_score{$n}") => array(
            'name' => get_option("scoreboard_option_name{$n}"),
            'picture' => get_option("scoreboard_option_image{$n}"),
            'car' => get_option("scoreboard_option_carimage{$n}"),
        )
    ));
}
?>

<div class="row">
<?php
// Get top 3 scores
krsort($racers);
$top3 = (array_slice($scorelist, 0, 3));

// Use key in top3 to determine which name, car and picture it relates to
foreach ($top3 as $score => $data) {
?>
    <div class="column" style="float: left; width: 33.33%; padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 35px; border-bottom: 2px solid red; height: 493px;">
        <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_0  et_pb_text_align_center">
            <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
                <!-- Racer Image -->
                <img src="<?php echo $data['picture']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $data['name']; ?>">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
        <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_1  et_pb_text_align_center">
            <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
                <h2 style="font-size: calc(0.7em + 1vw)">
                    <!-- Racer Name -->
                    <?php echo $data['name']; ?>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
        <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_2  et_pb_text_align_center">
            <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
                <h4> 
                    <b>
                        <?php echo "{$score} points" ?>
                    </b>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
        <div class="et_pb_code_inner" style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="<?php echo $data['car']; ?>" class="et_pb_lightbox_image"><img src="<?php echo $data['car']; ?>" alt="" class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-30280" width="200"></a>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
<?php 
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to show the 3 highest scores, not the first 3 inputs.

Comment: Now the score is showing up right but the name and image doesnt relate to the score.
Here is how its shown on the site
https://i.imgur.com/CHmyp11.png
Here is how the information is input
https://i.imgur.com/U9H4aHh.png

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for here is array sorting. Since I don't know what's the exact key to value pairing of the `$scorelist` array, I'll assume it's a numeric array with the scores stored as values, to sort this array you need to use [arsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) function.

```php
<?php
arsort($scorelist);

foreach($scorelist as $key => $score){
    echo $score;
}
```

This code will print you the scores based on their highest values. From there on you can add your HTML and other values by using the `$key` inside the foreach, that will give you the index number of the element so you can access your other list elements with it.